# What are the most overlooked uses of body language in team sports?

Tags: sports-psychology

In 20 years or so of practising different sports (mainly basketball, football, volleyball, rugby, quidditch) at vastly different levels, I've come across applications of body language and its interpretation. A couple of brief examples:

- Fakes/Defence in general: these have an element of actively using your body language (forcing a choice by the opponent, tricking them...) and one of interpreting your opponent's own body language
- "Appear weak when you are strong, and strong when you are weak": the quote is from *The Art of War* but it applies to sports just as well; it's possible to force your opponent's in being overly cautious, overly aggressive, misinterpret your intentions...
- Teamwork: by learning your teammate's body language, you can improve communication and teamwork without need of extensive verbal communication
- Influencing referees: taken to the extremes of flopping and diving, it can be crucial to draw referee calls
- etc.

I am interested in finding more applications of active use and/or interpretation of other players' body language that are relevant in team sports (potentially interested in individual sports too, but I'm trying limit the scope of the question slightly).
Bonus points for non-obvious examples, such as ones that would only be used by top level athletes. Both sport-specific and generic answers are welcome!

Comment: In baseball, an outfielder can act like he can't see a fly ball to bait baserunners to go, only to catch it and throw them out. Also, hidden ball tricks include deceptive body language to an unsuspecting baserunner.